# The continuity of a vector-valued function $f:X\to \mathbb{R^n}$, where $X$ is a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $f:X\to \mathbb{R^n}$ be a vector-valued function on $X$. We define the $k^{th}$ coordinate function of $f$, which we denote by $f^k$, to be $p_k \circ f$ where $p_k: \mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ is the $k^{th}$ projection on $\mathbb{R^n}$. I proved that if $f$ is continuous then so is each coordinate function. However, i wonder if the converse is true; meaning that is it necessarily for $f$ to be continuous if each coordinate function is continuous?.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is called the universal property of [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Properties). It works for any collecion of topological spaces, not only $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Of course, all of the parlance about the product topology doesn't carry any substance and doesn't constitute a proof. All that means that your problem can be restated as proving that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$ as topological spaces, which still remains to be seen if it is true.

Comment: @logarithm what is your definition of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @Matematleta The same as yours. Even when you define product of topological spaces as some space that satisfies the universal property still doesn't solve this problem, because you still have to prove such an object exists.

Comment: @logarithm  you mean take the topological product (cartesian product with initial $\tau$ with respect to the projections) and prove that it is a product in the category $\mathcal {Top}$? This is routine, and is more or less "common knowledge", right?

Comment: @Matematleta But is exactly what this problem is asking. There is no substance in saying that it is true because it is true.

Comment: @logarithm Noone says "it is true cause its true". It is true because someone else showed it. This is one of the fundamentals that can be found in *lots* of books. But in order to find it, you should start with learning the name of the property. And also that $\mathbb{R}$ is irrelevant here. Makes the search process easier. As a bonus I even provided the first step in search.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the claim is true, and it is built in to the definition of the product topology, i.e. that the projections $\pi_i:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R:\ (x_1,\cdots, x_i,\cdots,\ x_n)\mapsto x_i$ are continuous.

For then, if $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$, then it is a union of intersections of sets of the form

$$\pi^{-1}_i(U_i);\ U_i\  \text{open in}\  \mathbb R;\ \ 1\le i\le n.$$

Now, if the $(f_i)$ are continuous, the result follows easily from the fact that the $(\pi_i)$ are continuous, and 
$f_i=\pi_i\circ f:$

Let $U$ be a subbasis element in $\mathbb R^n$. Then, there is a $U=\pi_i^{-1}(V)$ for some open $V\subset \mathbb R.$ Then, $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}\circ \pi_i^{-1}(V)=(\pi_i\circ f)^{-1}(V)=f_i^{-1}(V)$, which is open because $f_i$ is assumed continuous.